# Getting Eclipse PDT nightly build from Hudson

Tags: eclipse

I have been looking for the most recent nightly build for PDT, but [the official download site](http://www.eclipse.org/epp/download.php) only has builds up to Sept 2010.

After some search, I was directed to their [CVS dashboard](https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/view/Athena%20CBI/job/cbi-pdt-2.2-helios/ws/build/) but I couldn't find a link to download the build. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Are you programming something to download this?

Comment: I just want to download it normally.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go.

1. On the dashboard, click the "workspace" link to the left.
2. Browse to "build" and then a timestamped directory; It's "N201101260913" at the minute.
3. Download the file which follows the format: "pdt-Update-N201101260913.zip".
4. Inside eclipse, go to "Help" and then "Install new software".
5. Click "Add". The name field can be left blank. Click the archive button and locate the ".zip" file you just downloaded.
6. You should now see available updates in the main pane. Click the checkbox to enable them and click next and just follow the instructions.

PS. Eclipse will probably complain about unsigned content, it should be okay to ignore as you know where the content has come from. The MD5 hash is there in the build directory if you need to verify the contents yourself.