# Eclipse Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Im getting an exception in my eclipse indigo - im using the PDT plugin as well.. any ideas? When i code the lines start acting funny, disappearing, then reappearing.

> Unhandled event loop exception
>
> java.lang.Error: Error: could not
>   match input   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XML10Names.zzScanError(XML10Names.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XML10Names.isValidXML10Name(XML10Names.java:588)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XML10Names.isValidXML10Name(XML10Names.java:271)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.provisional.NameValidator.isValid(NameValidator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DocumentImpl.isValidName(DocumentImpl.java:1015)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DocumentImpl.checkTagNameValidity(DocumentImpl.java:258)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.core.documentModel.dom.DOMDocumentForPHP.createElement(DOMDocumentForPHP.java:44)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.insertStartTag(XMLModelParser.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.insertStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelParser.java:1510)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.replaceStructuredDocumentRegions(XMLModelParser.java:2354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.handleRefresh(DOMModelImpl.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.nodesReplaced(DOMModelImpl.java:742)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument._fireEvent(BasicStructuredDocument.java:600)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.fireStructuredDocumentEvent(BasicStructuredDocument.java:1198)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.internalReplaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:1979)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2423)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2408)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument.access$2(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument$3.run(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.EditorExecutionContext.execute(EditorExecutionContext.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument.replaceText(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredDocumentToTextAdapter.replaceTextRange(StructuredDocumentToTextAdapter.java:1187)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.modifyContent(StyledText.java:7180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendKeyEvent(StyledText.java:7994)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.doContent(StyledText.java:2456)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKey(StyledText.java:5911)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:5941)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$7.handleEvent(StyledText.java:5635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1282)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1267)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendIMKeyEvent(Widget.java:1344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_commit(Control.java:2840)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.gtk_commit(Canvas.java:160)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1733)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5016)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4408)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_im_context_filter_keypress(Native Method)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_im_context_filter_keypress(OS.java:7793)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.filterKey(Control.java:2250)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_key_press_event(Control.java:3012)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_key_press_event(Composite.java:734)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1743)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5016)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4408)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:8394)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2258)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3207)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
>
> eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
>   java.version=1.6.0_22 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader
>   constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk,
>   NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -os
>   linux -ws gtk -arch x86

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain in a little more detail what exactly it is that you're doing that causes this?

Comment: i was just editing a php file which had html and php in it. I started typing <dt> and an autocomplete menu came up and it then started acting funny and threw that exception.

Comment: just chiming in that i'm experiencing the same problem. Mac 64-bit Indigo.

Answer (score 7):

NEW SOLUTION: There is new PDT Indigo bundle (3.0.2) which runs fine for me, out-of-the-box:
http://code.google.com/p/zend-sdk/downloads/list

OLD SOLUTION (PDT 3.0.0):

Thank you Valentin, I could fix my Eclipse. For me it worked from your link like that:

1. Open https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/cbi-pdt-3.0-indigo/lastStableBuild/artifact/build/
2. Click on build number N*
3. Download pdt-Update-N*.zip
4. In Eclipse goto "Install New Software"
5. Create a new site with archive and choose the downloaded zip
6. Now PDT is updated from the downloaded zip

Link updated, thanks to Daff!

Comment: This no longer works. For step #2, the ZIP url returns a 404.

Comment: That did it, thanks! The latest stable build can be found at https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/cbi-pdt-3.0-indigo/lastStableBuild/artifact/ then go into the build shown and download pdt-Update-*build-number*.zip

Comment: After trying the latest stable build as suggested in the comment above I was still getting a dependency error. This bug post did the trick to get past it - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354709

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in pdt that seems to be fixed: 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=350139

(I know I'm answering pretty late, but it will help other people that come from google)

---

edit: how I fixed it on my computer (and I don't recommend you to do it like me):

Got the latest stable nightly build of pdt from https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/cbi-pdt-3.0-indigo/ which for me was: https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/cbi-pdt-3.0-indigo/166/artifact/build/N201107150957/

There seems to be a way to update eclipse plugins by using pdt-Update-*.zip files explained here [Getting Eclipse PDT nightly build from Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142075/getting-eclipse-pdt-nightly-build-from-hudson) . I couldn't do that on my computer and I didn't had time to investigate why it didn't worked.  I got the other zip file (pdt-SDK-*.zip), removed the old plugins from eclipse library directory and put the new ones instead. It didn't work, the PHP perspective was nowhere to be found after that. So, I did a dirty hack: took org.eclipse.php.core_3.0.0.v201107150957.jar from the archive, removed the old one from the eclipse library directory (org.eclipse.php.core_3.0.0.v20110516-1100.jar in my case) and renamed the new one like the old one.

I am aware that this may break things and I don't recommend to other people to do that unless they do it as a temporary hackish fix :-)

I should have tried PDT 2 though...

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up my `Available Software Sites` preferences (Help>Install New Software), then updating Eclipse again (Help>Check for Updates) removed this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for this, it just happened to me, and found out that closing "AMD gaming evolved" application fixed it.. If I open it again it happens, just close that if you have it and try