# Eclipse Kepler - Unhandled event loop execution

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Installed Eclipse Kepler - Java EE version in my Windows 7 PC and getting this error message, whenever I click on Editor.

[image]
[image]

I have 'Package Explorer' opened on the left side and a Java file opened on the right side Editor, I click on something on the package explorer and when I click on the Java editor, I get the above error message pop up. I never received this error in my previous eclipse versions. Any way to fix this? Checked some SO posts related to this, but nothing fixed my problem.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554458/eclipse-unhandled-event-loop-exception

Comment: Now I receive this error in my Juno as well after I upgraded Juno to 'Service Release 2' from 1 (probably I should not have upgraded it). I don't have any other option than to use 'Indigo' :( It works OK in Indigo so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change(Increase) Memory Configuration on eclipse.ini :

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Might work, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

it's another program that causes this problem.
Most programs that causes this error are: 
Teamviewer,Folder Guard,or any program created by java language.
To find which program causes the error,open task manager,kill running programs in your windows one by one,and each time go bach to eclipse to check if the error is gone or not yet.