# Eclipse giving Error "Unhandled event loop exception" No more handles

Tags: android, eclipse, handler, eclipse-juno, conflicting-libraries

I am  getting this error after every 1-2 mins when i open the eclipse editor.I downloaded new eclipse still i get the same error with the new eclipse installed.This has been very frustating.Does any 1 have any knowledge about it.I am using eclipse Juno[image].Following is the Error that i get

```
![Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@2bdf75d8)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@5bb1ce68)}
Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@2bdf75d8)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.RedoActionHandler@5bb1ce68)}
Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.UndoActionHandler@30f41af6)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.operations.UndoActionHandler@2eb9eee9)}][2]
```

Comment: Make sure that your files are not duplicated within src and other folders

Comment: @Arju,I have downloaded new Eclipse and made a different Workspace.Just created a sample Hello World example.But I still get the same Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so long this issue finally got resolved.Nothing much just scanned my system with an Antivirus.May be some virus issue that caused eclipse behave weird.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/496362/

someone had the same bug.

some package caused his problem

or try here:
http://pujansrt.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/eclipse-unhandled-event-loop-exception.html

and i read somewhere else it is a mismatch with 32bit and 64bit versions

Comment: I am running 1 instance of eclipse also its 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's an eclipse bug

[Bug tracking eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287508)

You can also find a post in stackoverflow itself 
[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554458/eclipse-unhandled-event-loop-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from the 1st answer in this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles), and was able to solve this issue of mine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by "AMD Gaming Evolved", quit the program and the problem went away. So if someone gets this error - try quitting some programs, maybe there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

After you close the antivirus software and ad blocking software will be solved
You can try it.
close the antivirus software and ad blocking software, maybe be solved

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various methods, for me, the problem is related to ATI video card related driver, upon removal of the ATI Catalyst, updated WindowBuilder, the problem went away. I hope this helps.

I am running on Win7, 64-bit version with dual monitors.